# Git: Top commit different on local and branch after push

Tags: git

I have the following local and remote branches:

**Local**:  `mainline`, `myBranch`
**Remote**: `origin/mainline`, `origin/myBranch`

I made 4 commits on `myBranch`:

`c1`, `c2`, `c3`, and `c4`

and pushed them to `origin/myBranch`

And then I realized I needed some bug fixes commits `b1` and `b2` that were released into `origin/mainline` by someone else.

So I checked out `mainline` and did a `git pull`. I checked out to `myBranch` and then did a `rebase`. I know I screwed up here and I should have done just a `merge`. But anyway, this is what `myBranch` looked like at this point:

```
b1 b2 c1' c2' c3' c4'
```

And now I tried to do a `git push`. It of course did not let me do so until I do a `git pull`. So I do that and now `myBranch` looks like this:

```
b1 c1 c2 c3 c4 b2 c1' c2' c3' c4' mergecommit
```

Note that the latest commit is a merge commit that I think the pull introduced. I now go ahead and do a `git push`. I can also confirm that git said it succesfuly pushed till the hash of the merge commit.

But when I do a `git status` now, it says:

```
origin/myBranch and myBranch diverge by 1 commit.
```

Utterly confused I go and check the logs to find out that the latest commit on `myBranch` (the `mergecommit`) has a different hash from the `mergecommit` at the head of `origin/MyBranch`.

Help!! Why do these two merge commits have a different hash?

Comment: It's difficult to see what might have happened.  I can't reproduce locally based on the information you've given.  If you do a `git reflog`,  is there anything weird in there that might indicate why your latest commit differs from the remote?  Did you `--amend` the merge commit?

Comment: I did not do an ammend. However reflog tells me that the HEAD on my local branch moved to a new commit - and there is no comment to explain why it moved. This happened after the push.

Comment: If you do `git diff` between the two commit hashes, are they different?  If not, you can reset your local branch to match the remote version.  You can also `git show [commit]` to see what it changed (if anything)